# Snowflake Error parsing JSON: unfinished string, pos <number>

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to query a varchar column called "JsonCode" from the "Weather" table in snowflake. The "JsonCode" column looks like this:

```
{
  "Date": "2019-11-07T12:28:18",
  "CurrentTemp": "47Â°F",
  "WeatherIconStatus": "clear-day",
  "LowTemp": "21Â°F",
  "HighTemp": "50Â°F",
  "WindSpeed": "6 mph",
  "TempCategory": "Hot",
  "ForecastData": [
    {
      "Date": "2019-11-08T00:00:00",
      "WeatherIconStatus": "clear-day",
      "LowTemp": "26Â°F",
      "HighTemp": "51Â°F",
      "WindSpeed": "3 mph"
    },
    {
      "Date": "2019-11-09T00:00:00",
      "WeatherIconStatus": "clear-day",
      "LowTemp": "28Â°F",
      "HighTemp": "56Â°F",
      "WindSpeed": "7 mph"
    }
  ],
  "PrecipitationReportData": {
    "ReportDateTimeAsDate": "2019-11-07T04:45:14",
    "PrecipitationConditions": "",
    "ForecastText": "Clear",
    "NewPrecipitationReadings": {
      "Overnight": {
        "PrecipitationReading": "0in"
      },
      "TwentyFourHours": {
        "PrecipitationReading": "0in"
      },
      "FortyEightHours": {
        "PrecipitationReading": "0in"
      },
      "SevenDays": {
        "PrecipitationReading": "0in"
      }
    },
    "AreaReadings": {
      "City": {
        "PrecipitationReading": "0in"
      },
      "Town": {
        "PrecipitationReading": "0in"
      },
      "Highway": {
        "PrecipitationReading": null
      }
    },
    "SeasonPrecipitation": {
      "PrecipitationReading": "44in"
    }
  },
  "Links": [
    {
      "Href": "https://weather.com",
      "Rel": "self",
      "Method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am specifically trying to grab the "WindSpeed" data from 2019-11-07. I created a query that looks like this.

```
SELECT value:WindSpeed::varchar FROM "DATABASE"."DBO"."WEATHER" 
    , lateral flatten(input => PARSE_JSON(JsonCode):windspeed);
```

The response I received is

```
Error parsing JSON: unfinished string, pos <number>
```

I have been unable to find any documentation around this error. Any help is appreciated.
Note: I cut out some of the Json since there is multiple days of forecasted data.

Comment: Have you checked the actual JSON in a JSON checker, such as [this](https://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: Yes! This was one of the first things I checked and it was clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work without the need of a lateral flatten:

```sql
select parse_json(j):WindSpeed
from data
```

With the posted sample JSON:

```sql
with data as (
select $${
  "Date": "2019-11-07T12:28:18",
  "CurrentTemp": "47Â°F",
  "WeatherIconStatus": "clear-day",
  "LowTemp": "21Â°F",
  "HighTemp": "50Â°F",
  "WindSpeed": "6 mph",
  "TempCategory": "Hot",
  "ForecastData": [
    {
      "Date": "2019-11-08T00:00:00",
      "WeatherIconStatus": "clear-day",
      "LowTemp": "26Â°F",
      "HighTemp": "51Â°F",
      "WindSpeed": "3 mph"
    },
    {
      "Date": "2019-11-09T00:00:00",
      "WeatherIconStatus": "clear-day",
      "LowTemp": "28Â°F",
      "HighTemp": "56Â°F",
      "WindSpeed": "7 mph"
    }
  ],
  "PrecipitationReportData": {
    "ReportDateTimeAsDate": "2019-11-07T04:45:14",
    "PrecipitationConditions": "",
    "ForecastText": "Clear",
    "NewPrecipitationReadings": {
      "Overnight": {
        "PrecipitationReading": "0in"
      },
      "TwentyFourHours": {
        "PrecipitationReading": "0in"
      },
      "FortyEightHours": {
        "PrecipitationReading": "0in"
      },
      "SevenDays": {
        "PrecipitationReading": "0in"
      }
    },
    "AreaReadings": {
      "City": {
        "PrecipitationReading": "0in"
      },
      "Town": {
        "PrecipitationReading": "0in"
      },
      "Highway": {
        "PrecipitationReading": null
      }
    },
    "SeasonPrecipitation": {
      "PrecipitationReading": "44in"
    }
  },
  "Links": [
    {
      "Href": "https://weather.com",
      "Rel": "self",
      "Method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}$$ j
)

select parse_json(j):WindSpeed
from data
```

Comment: Ha that works! But the data is being held in the weather table which is updated daily. So I will need to query from the weather table and cant bring the data out of the table.

Comment: Then your query should be `select parse_json(JsonCode):WindSpeed from "DATABASE"."DBO"."WEATHER"`. The json you posted here is valid, maybe the error came from an invalid json? In any case, the flatten seems unnecessary.

Comment: Just double checked the json in a checker and the full json is valid. I ran this code again received the same error. I think the problem may stem that the column type for "jsoncode" is a varchar and this parse_json function is meant for varint type. I am unable to change the column type.

Comment: Can you make that string go through a base64 encode and share the results? Then we will be sure everything is working (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/base64_encode.html). Also try to do this https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_parse_json.html with try_parse_json.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out by using try_parse_json it was determined not every entry in the jsoncode column had valid Json. The character limit was reached on some records. At the end of the day I used this code for my query. ```select
      Try_parse_json(JSONCODE) as raw_json
    , raw_json:PrecipitationOvernight as PrecipitationOvernight
    , RAW_JSON:ForecastData[0]."Date"
    , RAW_JSON:ForecastData[0]."WeatherIconStatus"
from "DATABASE"."DBO"."WEATHER"  ```

Comment: Cool! Maybe incomplete JSON objects can be repaired too eventually